# No Reverse Match error

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm trying to make quiz_application by referring this one.https://github.com/tomwalker/django_quiz

When i try to access category page, i get this error.

```
NoReverseMatch at /quiz/category/
Reverse for 'quiz_category_list_matching' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['quiz/category/(?P<category_name>[\\w-]+)/$']
```

My files are following,
urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from .views import QuizListView, CategoriesListView,\
    ViewQuizListByCategory, QuizUserProgressView, QuizDetailView


urlpatterns = patterns('quiz.views',

                       url(regex=r'^$',
                           view=QuizListView.as_view(),
                           name='quiz_index'),

                       url(regex=r'^category/$',
                           view=CategoriesListView.as_view(),
                           name='quiz_category_list_all'),

                       url(regex=r'^category/(?P<category_name>[\w.-]+)/$',
                           view=ViewQuizListByCategory.as_view(),
                           name='quiz_category_list_matching'),


                       url(regex=r'^progress/$',
                           view=QuizUserProgressView.as_view(),
                           name='quiz_progress'),

                       #  passes variable 'quiz_name' to quiz_take view
                       url(regex=r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$',
                           view=QuizDetailView.as_view(),
                           name='quiz_start_page'),

                       url(regex=r'^(?P<quiz_name>[\w-]+)/take/$',
                           view='quiz_take',
                           name='quiz_question'),
                       )
```

views.py

```
import random

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render, render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView, TemplateView

from .models import Quiz, Category, Progress, Sitting, Question


class QuizListView(ListView):
    model = Quiz


class QuizDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Quiz
    slug_field = 'url'


class CategoriesListView(ListView):
    model = Category


class ViewQuizListByCategory(ListView):
    model = Quiz
    template_name = 'view_quiz_category.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ViewQuizListByCategory, self)\
            .get_context_data(**kwargs)

        category = get_object_or_404(Category,
                                     category=self.kwargs['category_name'])
        context['category'] = category
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        category = get_object_or_404(Category,
                                     category=self.kwargs['category_name'])
        queryset = super(ViewQuizListByCategory, self).get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(category=category)


class QuizUserProgressView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'progress.html'

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(QuizUserProgressView, self)\
            .dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(QuizUserProgressView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        progress = get_object_or_404(Progress, user=self.request.user)
        context['cat_scores'] = progress.list_all_cat_scores()
        context['exams'] = progress.show_exams()

        return context


def quiz_take(request, quiz_name):
    quiz = Quiz.objects.get(url=quiz_name.lower())

    if request.user.is_authenticated() is True:
        return user_load_sitting(request, quiz)

    else:  # anon user
        return anon_load_sitting(request, quiz)


def user_load_sitting(request, quiz):
    if quiz.single_attempt is True and\
       Sitting.objects.filter(user=request.user,
                              quiz=quiz,
                              complete=True)\
                      .count() > 0:

        return render(request, 'single_complete.html')

    try:
        sitting = Sitting.objects.get(user=request.user,
                                      quiz=quiz,
                                      complete=False)

    except Sitting.DoesNotExist:
        sitting = Sitting.objects.new_sitting(request.user, quiz)

    except Sitting.MultipleObjectsReturned:
        sitting = Sitting.objects.filter(user=request.user,
                                         quiz=quiz,
                                         complete=False)[0]

    finally:
        return user_load_next_question(request, sitting, quiz)


def user_load_next_question(request, sitting, quiz):
    previous = False
    if 'guess' in request.GET:
        progress, created = Progress.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
        guess = request.GET['guess']
        question = sitting.get_first_question()
        is_correct = question.check_if_correct(guess)

        if is_correct is True:
            sitting.add_to_score(1)
            progress.update_score(question.category, 1, 1)

        else:
            sitting.add_incorrect_question(question)
            progress.update_score(question.category, 0, 1)

        if quiz.answers_at_end is not True:
            previous = {'previous_answer': guess,
                        'previous_outcome': is_correct,
                        'previous_question': question,
                        'answers': question.get_answers(),
                        'question_type': {question.__class__.__name__: True}}

        sitting.remove_first_question()

    next_q = sitting.get_first_question()
    if next_q is False:
        #  no questions left
        return final_result_user(request, sitting, quiz, previous)

    return render_to_response('question.html',
                              {'quiz': quiz,
                               'question': next_q,
                               'question_type': {next_q.__class__.__name__:
                                                 True},
                               'answers': next_q.get_answers(),
                               'previous': previous},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))


def final_result_user(request, sitting, quiz, previous):
    score = sitting.get_current_score
    incorrect = sitting.get_incorrect_questions()
    max_score = quiz.get_max_score
    incorrect_score = max_score - score
    percent = sitting.get_percent_correct

    sitting.mark_quiz_complete()

    if quiz.exam_paper is False:  # if we do not plan to store the outcome
        sitting.delete()

    if quiz.answers_at_end is False:
        return render_to_response('result.html',
                                  {'quiz': quiz,
                                   'score': score,
                                   'max_score': max_score,
                                   'incorrect_score':incorrect_score,
                                   'percent': percent,
                                   'previous': previous},
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        questions = quiz.get_questions()
        return render_to_response('result.html',
                                  {'quiz': quiz,
                                   'score': score,
                                   'max_score': max_score,
                                   'incorrect_score':incorrect_score,
                                   'percent': percent,
                                   'questions': questions,
                                   'incorrect_questions': incorrect},
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))


def anon_load_sitting(request, quiz):
    if quiz.single_attempt is True:
        return render(request, 'single_complete.html')

    if quiz.anon_q_list() in request.session:
        return load_anon_next_question(request, quiz)
    else:
        return new_anon_quiz_session(request, quiz)


def new_anon_quiz_session(request, quiz):
    """
    Sets the session variables when starting a quiz for the first time
    """
    request.session.set_expiry(259200)  # expires after 3 days
    questions = quiz.get_questions()
    question_list = [question.id for question in questions]
    if quiz.random_order is True:
        random.shuffle(question_list)

    # session score for anon users
    request.session[quiz.anon_score_id()] = 0

    # session list of questions
    request.session[quiz.anon_q_list()] = question_list

    return load_anon_next_question(request, quiz)


def load_anon_next_question(request, quiz):
    previous = False

    if 'guess' in request.GET:
        previous = question_check_anon(request, quiz)
        request.session[quiz.anon_q_list()] = (request.
                                               session[quiz.anon_q_list()][1:])

    if not request.session[quiz.anon_q_list()]:
        return final_result_anon(request, quiz, previous)

    next_question_id = request.session[quiz.anon_q_list()][0]
    next_question = Question.objects.get_subclass(id=next_question_id)
    question_type = {next_question.__class__.__name__: True}
    return render_to_response('question.html',
                              {'quiz': quiz,
                               'question': next_question,
                               'question_type': question_type,
                               'previous': previous},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))


def question_check_anon(request, quiz):
    question = Question.objects.get_subclass(id=request.GET['question_id'])
    is_correct = question.check_if_correct(request.GET['guess'])

    if is_correct is True:
        request.session[quiz.anon_score_id()] += 1
        anon_session_score(request, 1, 1)
    else:
        anon_session_score(request, 0, 1)

    if quiz.answers_at_end is not True:
        return {'previous_answer': request.GET['guess'],
                'previous_outcome': is_correct,
                'previous_question': question}
    else:
        return {}


def anon_session_score(request, to_add=0, possible=0):
    """
    Returns the session score for non-signed in users.
    If number passed in then add this to the running total and
    return session score

    examples:
        anon_session_score(1, 1) will add 1 out of a possible 1
        anon_session_score(0, 2) will add 0 out of a possible 2
        x, y = anon_session_score() will return the session score
                                    without modification
    """
    if "session_score" not in request.session:
        request.session["session_score"] = 0
        request.session["session_score_possible"] = 0

    if possible > 0:
        request.session["session_score"] = (request.session["session_score"] +
                                            to_add)

        request.session["session_score_possible"] = \
            (request.session["session_score_possible"] + possible)

    return request.session["session_score"], \
        request.session["session_score_possible"]


def final_result_anon(request, quiz, previous):
    score = request.session[quiz.anon_score_id()]
    max_score = quiz.get_max_score
    incorrect_score = max_score - score
    percent = int(round((float(score) / max_score) * 100))
    if score is 0:
        score = "0"

    session_score, session_possible = anon_session_score(request)
    del request.session[quiz.anon_q_list()]

    if quiz.answers_at_end is False:
        return render_to_response('result.html',
                                  {'score': score,
                                   'max_score': max_score,
                                   'incorrect_score':incorrect_score,
                                   'percent': percent,
                                   'previous': previous,
                                   'session': session_score,
                                   'possible': session_possible},
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        questions = quiz.get_questions()
        return render_to_response('result.html',
                                  {'score': score,
                                   'max_score': max_score,
                                   'incorrect_score':incorrect_score,
                                   'percent': percent,
                                   'questions': questions,
                                   'session': session_score,
                                   'possible': session_possible},
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

category_list.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}All Quizzes{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h2>Category list</h2>

<ul>
  {% for cat in category_list %}
  <li>
    <a href="{% url 'quiz_category_list_matching' category_name=cat.category %}">
      {{ cat.category }}
    </a>
  </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>

{% endblock %}
```

I think the problem is url.py because i got some information when i searched.
Which part is wrong?

- i understand the problem is that i cannot pass category_name in category_list.html to urls.py because when i remove `<a href="{% url 'quiz_category_list_matching' category_name=cat.category %}">`, it works even though the category list is not linked.
  could you give me some idea to resolve this problem.

Comment: Your urls.py is formed correctly, and so is the url template tag.

Comment: What happens if you call reverse() on `'quiz_category_list_matching'` from the shell?

Comment: From the error your can see that cat.category is not returning anything. Check that

Comment: `with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}'`

Comment: And from your views I see no category_list assignment anywhere.

Comment: @petkostas this class is category_list assignment.

Comment: @petkostas class CategoriesListView(ListView):
    model = Category

Comment: @agconti i don't know how to call reverse() on shell. so i will search and try it

Comment: @user3914622 you should use `context_object_name=category_list` otherwise your categories are reffered as `object_list ` and not `category_list` in the template.

Comment: @petkostas i change it to object_list but still doesn't work

Comment: @petkostas {% for cat in object_list %}
  <li>
 <a href="{% url 'quiz_category_list_matching' category_name=cat.category %}">
   {{ cat.category }}
 </a>
  </li>

Comment: also do any of your Category objects have blank category field values?

Comment: @sHtev ya, its blank. I've done {{ Category_list|pprint }} and got ''

Comment: @sHtev `class Category(models.Model):

    category = models.CharField(max_length=250,
                                blank=True,
                                unique=True,
                                null=True)

    objects = CategoryManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Category"
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.category)
`

Comment: @sHtev this is `class Category(models.Model)`.

Comment: what I mean is that a) do you have actual Category objects existing in your database (otherwise the for loop would not be looking for anything) and b) do any of those Category objects have a blank value for category? You probably shouldn't allow blank=True in this case.

Comment: @sHtev a) yes, i think i have because i add category object from my admin page. b)i change blank=True to False. but still doesn't work.

Comment: have you got a fork of your entire project on github to look at?

Comment: @sHtev i haven't got the fork....

Comment: @agconti i called reverse from my shell. then i got this code.

Comment: @agconti `>>> reverse('quiz_category_list_matching')
packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 452, in _reverse_with_prefix
    (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'quiz_category_list_matching' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['quiz/category/(?P<category_name>[\\w.-]+)/$']`

Comment: you need some parameters in that reverse call

Comment: reverse('quiz_category_list_matching', category_name=<name>), where <name> is a known category name - this at least will show the category detail template works ok

Comment: Do you have any categories defined?

Comment: Also, would you be able to post it up as an issue on the github repo?

Answer (score 0):

Django in CBV's by default assigns the model to `object_list` in order to override the assignment name change the `context_object_name` attribute:

```
class CategoriesListView(ListView):
    model = Category
    context_object_name = "category_list"
```

Comment: {{ object_list|pprint }} in your template, does it actually exist? if it doesn't work you start from the basics, which is that cat is probably empty.

Comment: i got this one when i type {{object_list|pprint}}. [<Quiz: Greeting>, <Quiz: number>, <Quiz: Basic Words>, <Quiz: position>]

Comment: which implies model is being set to Quiz not Category for this template